# How to get the exact storage size of an android application

Tags: android

When I got a low phone storage error I saw flipboard taken 75mb but programatically I can only see 16mb as the size of data directory.
How to match the size is there something I am missing

Comment: is this related to programming ?

Comment: yes. I am trying to find what all locations other than /data should I look for to get exact size

Comment: Is Flipboard using a folder in storage/Android/ ?
Else, look at Settings > Application > FlipBoard and see if it's using cache.

Comment: You can't, without root. The Apk file itself is in `/data/app` or `/sdcard/.android_secure/` when the app is saved on SD card. Then you have `/data/dalvik-cache` where the dalvik code is stored which is basically extracted from the Apk. Then you also have `/data/app-lib` where the applications store their binary files (`*.so` for Apps that use code that runs natively instead of inside the dalvik VM) etc. Depending on the maybe even in `/cache/packagename/`